# In what way I can pinpoint the system calls and CPU instructions without debugger?

Tags: profiling, cpu, reverse-engineering

In my case, debugger cannot be used to analysis the assembly code of a running program.
My goal is to pinpoint the calls and instructions of a running application within a period of time, including their corresponding addresses and instructions.

I have been trying to do it by CPU profiling or instruction-based sampling but it seems to be not capable in analyzing any application that is already running.

Is it possible to achieve my goal without using debuggers?
If yes, can you give me suggestions to do that?

Comment: I've done it with an In-Circuit Emulator (ICE), also known as an Intel "Blue Box". I don't know any other way, short of a debugger.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey so this is the hardware solution to the problem
Anyone can suggest solutions in software?

Comment: You can try intel's pin : https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pin-a-dynamic-binary-instrumentation-tool